# Insert Checkboxes in to PHP Post Array

Tags: php, html, mysql

Sorry for daft question.  I have a form with multiple dynamically generated checkboxes,  I want to insert these in to a post array to move them on to the next page then manipulate them.

The form:

```
<form action="campcreate.php" class="form" method="post">
<label for "campName">Campaign Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="campName" class="form-control" name="campName" placeholder="Campaign Name" required minlength="6" autofocus>
<label for "notes">Description:</label>
<textarea class="form-control" name="notes" rows="5" id="notes" placeholder="Add any useful notes or descriptions here"></textarea>
<h3>Select committee memmbers:</h3>
<p>Committee members can be changed as required,  all members selected as committee members will be able to view documents, meetings etc. connected to the campaign.</p>
<p>Assigning a committee member does <strong>not</strong> grant them any different admin privillages on the site.</p>
<?php getnames(); ?>

<div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-right" id="create">Next</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right" id="restart">Back</button>
</div> <!--Form Div--->
</form>
```

The included function:

```
function getnames(){
    global $conn;
$sqlga = "SELECT user_id, user_first, user_last FROM users WHERE (usr_acrive= 1) AND (perm!=0) ORDER BY user_last ASC";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);    
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sqlga);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($row['user_id']!=$_SESSION['user_id']){
        $checked="";
    }else{
        $checked="checked disabled";
    }
    echo '<input type="checkbox"'.$checked.' value="'. $row['user_id'] .'" name="userid"> '.$row['user_first'] . ' '. $row['user_last'] .  '<br>';
   }
}
```

I want to carry these forward these check boxes (which display correctly) to the next page but I can't work out how to include these in the post, one box will be automatically selected (the user creating the post) but up to say 100 other boxes may be ticked.

I've tried echoing out, but I can only see the text boxes.

Any pointers welcome.

Comment: "I've tried echoing out, but I can only see the text boxes." did you try to check the browsers source if it is there and did you validate the html?.. Because broken html might not display correctly in a browser.. besides `<input type="checkbox"'.$checked.'`  looks suspect because it looks like it is missing a space there.

Comment: Did you verify that your program is calling the function getnames, Did you verify `SELECT user_id, user_first, user_last FROM users WHERE (usr_acrive= 1) AND (perm!=0) ORDER BY user_last ASC` gives results in your SQL program like PHPMyAdmin? And did you verify your program is getting into the while loop?

Comment: Yes,  I'm satisfied the SQL query behaves as expected as the check-boxes are dynamically generated and are displaying correctly.

Answer (score 0):

post info is sent by the input tag's name

you're looping and adding inputs with the same name:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox"'.$checked.' value="'. $row['user_id'] .'" name="userid"> '.$row['user_first'] . ' '. $row['user_last'] . '<br>';
```

you should try creating a unique name when echoing, depending on the manipulation you need...

for example (inside the foreach loop) :

```
$i++;
echo '<input type="checkbox"'.$checked.' value="'. $row['user_id'] .'" name="userid"'. $i. '> '.$row['user_first'] . ' '. $row['user_last'] . '<br>';
```

Comment: Many thanks Guy L.

This by my limited knowledge will loop out each checkbox with a unique name and post them with a unique name,  my concern and the bit I can't wrap my mind around is what happens at the action page,  if I want to simply echo out these checkboxes how would I do this,  or do I need to loop them back in to an array for posting?  Forgive my newbie questions and thanks for your help.

Comment: you need to loop through your array and echo the checkboxes, like hou did... they should all be displayed. think of the unique key you want to return back to the code, and echo that as tbe name